# Need some time sheet merging advise

Tags: microsoft-excel

I wanteed to check if someone can help generating the report to total the days. In the example Cell G should have the result of the dates given. I tried sumif and sumproduct and for some reason it's not giving me the result I need. Thank you.

```
LOGIN TIMESTAMP             In          LOGOUT TIMESTAMP            Out      LOGIN TIME
Mon, 18 Jan 2021 12:54:30   12:54:30    Mon, 18 Jan 2021 18:34:37   18:34:37    5:40:07
Mon, 18 Jan 2021 20:24:14   20:24:14    Mon, 18 Jan 2021 21:01:10   21:01:10    0:36:56
Tue, 19 Jan 2021 11:54:47   11:54:47    Tue, 19 Jan 2021 21:00:21   21:00:21    9:05:34
Wed, 20 Jan 2021 11:38:15   11:38:15    Wed, 20 Jan 2021 21:12:22   21:12:22    9:34:07
Fri, 22 Jan 2021 00:12:17   00:12:17    Fri, 22 Jan 2021 04:59:15   04:59:15    4:46:59
Fri, 22 Jan 2021 04:59:30   04:59:30    Fri, 22 Jan 2021 10:01:59   10:01:59    5:02:29
Mon, 25 Jan 2021 00:11:08   00:11:08    Mon, 25 Jan 2021 10:00:17   10:00:17    9:49:09
Tue, 26 Jan 2021 22:47:21   22:47:21    Wed, 27 Jan 2021 08:07:31   08:07:31    9:20:10
Wed, 27 Jan 2021 22:53:19   22:53:19    Thu, 28 Jan 2021 08:00:20   08:00:20    9:07:01
```

[image: IMG:]

Ideally the data here is ok but the date for January 22, I was hoping that the cell will add it automatically if its in the range of a certain schedule

Comment: Edit your question, and instead of supplying an image, supply the text. That will make it easier to work with your data... (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501/9347919 for how to do this, and this to generate tables from your data: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)

Answer (score 1):

As you are calculating the login time based on the date, then SUMIF should work. I used only the date and login column as seen on the image below.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,$F2,$B$2:$B$7)
```

In your case, you must change the sum range from `$B$2:$B$7` to `$D$2:$D$7`. Your formula will be like the below. Obviously change the cell range also as you have more data on your spreadsheet.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,$F2,$D$2:$D$7)
```

[image]